# How do I get the current date in typst?

Tags: typst

I would like to insert the current date in the title section of my document (a-la LaTeX). Is it even possible to do so yet? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to obtain today's date since Typst v0.5.0; simply use the `datetime.today()` function, which returns a `datetime` object containing the current day, month and year (see here for reference: https://typst.app/docs/reference/construct/datetime/#datetime-today). Note that in Typst there is, currently, no way to get the current *time* (i.e., hours/minutes/seconds), however (just the current date).

You can combine this with datetime's `display()` method to display the datetime in your desired way (see https://typst.app/docs/reference/types/datetime/#methods-display for reference), or use the `.day()` / `.month()` / `.year()` datetime methods directly:

```js
#let today = datetime.today()
#today.display()  // use the default format: year-month-day

#today.display("[day]/[month]/[year]")  // specify a custom format

#today.display("[month repr:long] [day], [year]")  // or another custom format

#today.day() / #today.month() / #today.year()  // you can also do this (not zero-padded)
// the methods above return integers directly which can be used in scripting
```

On the 12th of September of 2023, UTC (when this answer was written), the Typst code above will produce (on Typst v0.7.0, using the rendering bot on Discord):

[image: Output of the sample code, including four lines, from top to bottom (excluding the double quotes): "2023-09-12", "12/09/2023", "September 12, 2023" and "12 / 9 / 2023"]

Answer (score 4):

It's currently not possible. However, there is an open [Pull Request](https://github.com/typst/typst/pull/435) that aims to add that functionality.

EDIT: It is now possible. See [@pgsuper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77085410/).

Comment: It is now possible as of version 0.5.0 using datetime.today().